# Using ansible check ssh passwdless login, if not working, copy pub key to the remote host

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am learning ansible, this is my playbook,

```
---
- name: Check passwdless login
  #hosts: stage-servers
  hosts: Testing-Server
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
        - name: check ssh to remote hosts works
          register: ssh_connection_test
          shell: "hostname; id"
          ignore_errors: yes
        - debug:
             msg: "Testing ssh_connection_test.stderr"
        - name: Task passwdless login failed, do ssh-copy-id
          register: ssh_copy_id_result
          shell: "/usr/local/bin/sshpass -f ~/.ssh/psk ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub \"root@{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} \""
          when: "'.*Failed.*' in ssh_connection_test.stderr"
        - debug:
             var: ssh_copy_id_result
~*
```

when first task failed, the playbook not proceeding with the next task. Please help me to resolve this issue,

**Output of this playbook is:**

```
-bash-4.1# ansible-playbook passwordless.yml 

PLAY [Check passwdless login] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [check ssh to remote hosts works] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Address x.x.x.x maps to test.testlab.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!\r\nPermission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
    to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/passwordless.retry

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
x.x.x.x                 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Comment: you need to find a way inject your ssh public key, before execute ansible.

Answer (score 2):

Change ignore_errors: yes to ignore_unreachable: yes

ignore_unreachable will allow Ansible to not fail when you hit the unreachable error you are after.
This will then allow for the task to run to copy the ssh key to the remote machine.

Does require Ansible 2.7 or above

As an extra the when on the shell task can also be adjusted to

```
when: ssh_connection_test.unreachable is defined and ssh_connection_test.unreachable
```

This uses the inbuilt bool in the returned error and also a check to make sure it is defined in case the ssh connection was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, the play breaks when Ansible decides it can’t reach the target server.

From the top of my head I can think of two ways of dealing with this sort of problem:

- If you deploy template machines, include an ssh public key in the template (storing the private key securely, of course).
- If that’s not an option, set up a separate server initialization playbook which ensures the public ssh key is in place and configures ssh to your liking, after which you can use PKI-based authentication for deploying all future roles.

Comment: I tried with seperate playbook to do ssh-copy-id, but still I am getting permission denied error message.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a reverse mapping ssh error.  The server is seeing your IP address map to a DNS name but that DNS name does not map back to the IP address.

Here are three suggestions from the reference below on how to fix this problem:

1. Setup a Reverse DNS Record (aka PTR Record) for the SSH client.
2. Ensure UseDNS no and GSSAPIAuthentication no are set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the SSH server, then restart the sshd.
3. Confirm that /etc/hosts on the SSH server has an entry for the SSH client IP address and hostname.

The third suggestion is probably the quickest solution to see if it solves your issue.

**References**

["reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo" and "POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT" error messages via SSH](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/83933)

[rsh/ssh problem: POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT, most probably due to DNS configuration](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/rsh-ssh-problem-possible-break-in-attempt-most-probably-due-to-dns-configuration-921803/)